# Ajax загрузка постов по клику WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, ajax, ajax-load

Казалось бы простая тема, но испробовала очень много способов и ни один не работает для меня. Копка нажимается, пишет "Загружаю...", но следующие посты не выводятся, не пойму в чем проблема. Вот мой код:

Это у меня в файле front-page.php

```php
<div class="blog-content__row js-blog-slider">
    <?php
        $mypost_Query = new WP_Query( array(
        'posts_per_page'   => 6,
        'cat' => array(5,6,7),
        'orderby' => 'data',
        'order' => 'ASC'
        ) );

        if ( $mypost_Query->have_posts() ) :
            while ( $mypost_Query->have_posts() ) : $mypost_Query->the_post(); ?>
                <div class="blog-content__item-col">
                    <article class="blog-card">
                        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
                            <div class="blog-card__header">
                                <h3 class="blog-card__title"><?php the_title(); ?></h3>
                                <img class="blog-card__img" src="<?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail_url( $post->ID, 'full' ); ?>" alt="Заголовок новости" />
                            </div>
                        </a>
                        <div class="blog-card__body">
                            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
                                <p class="blog-card__text">
                                    <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
                                </p>
                            </a>
                            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="blog-card__link btn btn_secondary btn_arrow btn_arrow-grey">подробнее</a>
                        </div>
                    </article>
                </div>
                <?php endwhile; wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
                <?php if (  $mypost_Query->max_num_pages > 1 ) : ?>
                <script>
                    var ajaxurl = '<?php echo site_url() ?>/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php';
                    var true_posts = '<?php echo serialize($mypost_Query->query_vars); ?>';
                    var current_page = <?php echo (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
?>;
                    var max_pages = '<?php echo $mypost_Query->max_num_pages; ?>';
                </script>
                <div id="true_loadmore">Загрузить ещё</div>
                <?php endif;
            endif;
            ?>
    </div>
```

Далее код jQuery:

```js
jQuery(function ($) {
    $('#true_loadmore').click(function () {
        $(this).text('Загружаю...'); // изменяем текст кнопки, вы также можете добавить прелоадер
        var data = {
            'action': 'loadmore',
            'query': true_posts,
            'page': current_page
        };
        $.ajax({
            url: ajaxurl, // обработчик
            data: data, // данные
            type: 'POST', // тип запроса
            success: function (data) {
                if (data) {
                    $('#true_loadmore').text('Загрузить ещё').before(data); // вставляем новые посты
                    current_page++; // увеличиваем номер страницы на единицу
                    if (current_page == max_pages) $("#true_loadmore").remove(); // если последняя страница, удаляем кнопку
                } else {
                    $('#true_loadmore').remove(); // если мы дошли до последней страницы постов, скроем кнопку
                }
            }
        });
    });
});
```

И то что в functions.php

```php
function true_load_posts(){

        $args = unserialize( stripslashes( $_POST['query'] ) );
        $args['paged'] = $_POST['page'] + 1; // следующая страница
        $args['post_status'] = 'publish';
        $args['posts_per_page'] = 6; // по сколько записей подгружать
        $args['cat'] = array(5,6,7);
        $args['orderby'] = 'data';
        $args['order'] = 'ASC';

        // обычно лучше использовать WP_Query, но не здесь
        query_posts( $args );
        // если посты есть
        if( have_posts() ) :

            // запускаем цикл
            while( have_posts() ): the_post();

                echo '.
                    <div class="blog-content__item-col">
                        <article class="blog-card">
                            <a href="'. the_permalink() .'">
                                <div class="blog-card__header">
                                    <h3 class="blog-card__title">'. the_title() .'</h3>
                                    <!-- /.blog-card__title -->
                                    <img class="blog-card__img" src="'. get_the_post_thumbnail_url( $post->ID, 'full' ) .'" alt="Заголовок новости" />
                                </div>
                                <!-- /.blog-card__img -->
                            </a>
                            <!-- /.blog-card__header -->
                            <div class="blog-card__body">
                                <a href="'. the_permalink() .'">
                                    <p class="blog-card__text">
                                        '. the_excerpt() .'
                                    </p>
                                </a>
                                <!-- /.blog-card__text -->
                                <a href="'. the_permalink() .'" class="blog-card__link btn btn_secondary btn_arrow btn_arrow-grey">подробнее</a>
                                <!-- /.blog-card__link btn btn_secondary btn_arrow btn_arrow-grey -->
                            </div>
                            <!-- /.blog-card__body -->
                        </article>
                        <!-- /.blog-card -->
                    </div>
                .';

            endwhile;

        endif;
        die();
    }


    add_action('wp_ajax_loadmore', 'true_load_posts');
    add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_loadmore', 'true_load_posts');
```

Comment: Приложите скрин ответа от аякс запроса)

Comment: @WPPunk обычно лучше использовать WP_Query, но не здесь

Comment: @WPPunk к сожалению данный jquery взят с одной статьи, а сама не особо дружу с js, не могли бы вы подсказать как получить ответ?)

Comment: В хроме нажимаете F12 переходите на вкладку Console, проверяете есть ли там ошибки. Если нет переходите, на вкладку Network и смотрите что приходит от сервера при нажатии на вашу кнопку, тут [пример](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/network#details) Сразу можете переключиться на XHR чтобы лишнее отфильтровать.

Answer (score 0):

Мой совет - используйте [плагин](https://ru.wordpress.org/plugins/infinite-scroll-and-ajax-load-more/), там будет намного проще

Comment: Человек код пишет и у него все уже сделано на 90%) Зачем ему плагин?)

Comment: @vantal в данном случае любые плагины не кастомизируются именно так как мне надо, поэтому вариант с плагином отметаю

Comment: @Alexa Что именно не кастомизируется? В данном плагине есть шаблон вывода, настраиваете под себя. Главное на front-page.php добавить пагинацию, чтобы вывелась кнопка "load more"

Comment: @vantal попробовала через ваш плагин, даже через него просто бесконечно крутится загрузка и ничего не происходит

Comment: @Alexa Покопайтесь в настройках и прочтите документацию, должно получиться, я данный плагин использовал на 5-7 разных сайтов